# Audio/Video out of sync with PCM2704 USB key. How should I proceed?

Tags: raspbmc, audio, linux, kodi

I recently bought a PCM2704 USB sound card, which is purported to work out-of-the-box with raspbmc.  I've enabled the experimental audio drivers, but now I get pretty bad A/V sync issues.  Of course, I can tweak the audio offset in XBMC, but this is **1)** annoying as all hell to do for each video file and **2)** the offset is not stable -- it changes over time.

I know very little about linux audio, and I'm unsure how to proceed.  Any advice would be most welcome!

Comment: I will give you a proper answer later, but please check out my answer [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6807/mopidy-and-sound-quality/6810#6810)

Comment: @xxmbabanexx, Great!  Thank you!  I'm assuming the fact that our sound cards are built on different chipsets doesn't change anything?  I'll wait for your official answer, since it's unclear to me if anything is different in my particular case.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx, could I bother you for that proper answer? =)

Comment: sorry for the wait, I will try to answer you tonight. I have had a lot on my plate for the last weekend.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx, No problem!  I just wanted to make sure you hadn't forgotten.  I did try to run through the instructions you posted, but I'm still having some issues, so I must have done something wrong.

Comment: @AwesomeUser, I'm afraid I gave up (and ended up buying a new TV anyway), so I now do audio via HDMI.  I appreciate the effort you guys are putting into the Q&A!  Hopefully this problem is no longer a common one =/